# Php Timezone +/- Issue

Tags: php, time, timezone, format

```
 <?php 
    $ctime = time();
    print date("d-m-Y, g:i A", $ctime) . "  (+0)<br>";
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
    print date("d-m-Y, g:i A", $ctime) . "  (+8)<br>";
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-8');
    print date("d-m-Y, g:i A", $ctime) . "  (-8)<br>";
 ?>
```

So as you can see above I am messing with the time zones. The code works as expected and outputs 3 values.

```
26-11-2013, 9:10 PM (+0)
26-11-2013, 1:10 PM (+8)
27-11-2013, 5:10 AM (-8)
```

My issue has nothing to do with the script itself the time zones present nicely, except one issue. The time zones seem a bit off. The part I'm pointing out is the +8/-8 for some reason it is reversed. I live in PST(-8) and when the time zones are outputted they give of the reverse so when I set the time zone to +8 I am really getting -8 and vice-versa. Because even though it is +8 It matches my time perfectly. Am I doing something wrong or is it completely fine and I am just confused over nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Etc/GMT` timezones have their sign reversed, indeed behaving opposite to what you expect. See also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area):

> In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from what most people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)

Also, try to avoid these, locality based timezones can take DST into account, the `Etc/GMT` does not do that AFAIK.

I see [the manual also warns you](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php):

> Warning
>
> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.